# Linux: execute command after finishing of multiple curl commands

Tags: linux, bash

I have a list of curl commands in test.sh file

```
curl "www....." > 1.txt &
curl "www....." > 2.txt &
curl "www....." > 3.txt &
```

Note: i am using & so that all the curl commands can be executed at a time, without running one after another, which is pretty time consuming.

When only all the three curl commands are finished i want to execute the command:

```
cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > all.txt
```

How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `wait` to block until all preceding background jobs have completed.

```
curl "www....." > 1.txt &
curl "www....." > 2.txt &
curl "www....." > 3.txt &
wait
cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > all.txt
```